# How to make an app available in Apple's "Add to Wallet" screen?

Tags: applepay, passkit

So I was trying to add my Chase credit card manually to Apple Pay when I noticed this.
Chase app was listed on the "Add to Wallet" screen. See attached image - "From Apps on Your iPhone" section.

On tapping it, it authenticated me and listed my Chase cards that could be added to Apple Pay. All without needing to open the Chase app itself.
Is there a way where we could enable our app(that has payment pass provisioning entitlements) to appear in this list?[image]

Comment: Hi @akshay1188, I'm implementing apple wallet extension. I done all setup entitlement, plist. I added two extension (UI and Non UI). But my app is not showing in wallet app. Could plz help me, how your app is showing under the "From Apps on Your iphone"? I have an urgent requirement to implement this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is enabled when you setup a "Non UI Extension" in your project. The app extension needs to be able to call your backend and do the provisioning flow just like in-app.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/passkit/pkissuerprovisioningextensionhandler

There is documentation from Apple for this called:
Apple Pay In-App Provisioning Extensions for Payment Cards